# A tight bound on $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(p \alpha^i+(1-p))$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, logarithms

> If $0<p<1$ and $\alpha>1$, then find a tight  upper bound for 
>   $$S(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(p \alpha^i+(1-p))$$

**My solution:** Since $\ln(1+x)\leq x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
S(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(p \alpha^i+(1-p))&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} (p \alpha^i-p)\\
&= p \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha^i-n p\\
&= p  \frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\alpha}{\alpha-1}-n p
\end{align}

This is not a tight upper bound. Can anyone help me obtain a tighter upper-bound? I proved $S(n)=\mathcal{O}(\alpha^{n+1})$. I need a better order.

Using $\ln(1+x)\leq x -x^2/2+x^3/3$ yields a tighter bound, but I don't think it yields a smaller order that much.

Please leave me a comment if you think you know something helpful.

Comment: Just a side comment: If you use the concavity of log, you can prove a lower bound of $\frac{pn(n+1)}{2}\log(\alpha) $ but I'm not sure about ideas other than linear approximation for upper bounds. Out of curiosity, does this come up in maximum likelihood estimation somewhere?

Comment: Since $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(p \alpha^i+(1-p)) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(\alpha^i)$ when $\alpha>1$, you can easily get the upper bound $S(n) = O(n^2\ln\alpha)$. One can presumably do even better when $p$ is small, but Ravi's comment shows that this is essentially best possible otherwise.

Comment: @ravi it comes from relative entropy.

Comment: @ravi I found an answer and I think it is tight.

Comment: @GregMartin I found an answer and I think it is tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
S(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(p \alpha^i+(1-p))&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln\left(p \alpha^i \left(1 + \frac{1-p}{p \alpha^i}\right)\right)\\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\ln(p)+ i \ln(\alpha) + \ln\left(1+\frac{1-p}{p \alpha^i}\right)\right)  \\
&= n \ln(p) + \ln(\alpha) \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln\left(1+\frac{1-p}{p \alpha^i}\right)  \\
&\leq n \ln(p) + \ln(\alpha) \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1-p}{p \alpha^i} \\
&= n \ln(p) + \ln(\alpha) \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{1-p}{p} \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{1-(1/\alpha)^{n}}{1-1/\alpha}
\end{align}
Since $\alpha>1$, $S(n)$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.